# scipy evaluate distribution fitting (fitting error)

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

Given samples `X` I am able to estimate the parameters of the pareto distribution with scipy.

`X = np.random.pareto(2, 1000)
params = sp.stats.pareto.fit(X)
b, loc, scale = params`

Now given 2 datasets `X1` `X2` I want to know which one of them is more similar to a pareto distribution.

Consider for example:

`X1 = np.random.pareto(2, 1000)
X2 = np.random.pareto(2, 1000) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)`

the fit in the first case should return a lower error. 
How can I measure this error?

Comment: maybe I have found the solution https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.nnlf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.nnlf